# How to validate password and confirm password using AngularJs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to remove the validation message without entering any data. whenever I used the password and confirm the password there always an active error message. When I fill in the correct password then error messages are removed but the initial time is the active error message.

```html
<form name="myForm2" class="row gap-y input-round ng-pristine ng-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-invalid-compare-to" 
      data-ng-if="otpVerificationDone==true">
  <div class="col-12 mx-auto">
    <div class="form-group" data-ng-hide="passwordField">
      <input type="password" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-touched"
             name="newpassword" data-ng-model="userform.newpassword" 
             id="newpassword" placeholder="Password"
             data-ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&amp;])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&amp;]{8,20}$/"
             required="" aria-autocomplete="list">
        <span class="text-warning small-5">
        &nbsp;<span class="text-danger small-5 ng-hide" 
                    data-ng-show="myForm2.newpassword.$error.pattern">
                 Password must contain 8 characters, including Special/UPPER/lowercase and numbers.</span>&nbsp;
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" data-ng-hide="passwordField">
      <input type="password" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope
             ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required
             ng-invalid-compare-to" name="confirmpassword"
             data-ng-model="userform.confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" 
             placeholder="Password" data-compare-to="userform.newpassword" 
             required="">
        <span class="text-danger small-3">
        &nbsp;<span class="text-danger small-3" data-ng-show="myForm2.confirmpassword.$error.compareTo">Passwords do not match.</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" data-ng-hide="passwordField" class="btn btn-round btn-success" data-ng-disabled="myForm2.$invalid" data-ng-click="resetPassword()" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image: error image]

Comment: The `ng-invalid-compare-to` directive is not part of the AngularJS framework. Please either include the code for that directive or provide a link to the library that provides that directive.